Подставка цены из регистра сведений 1с
Документ «Заказ авто» фиксирует факт заказа
клиентом автомобиля для покупки.
Как сделать так что бы в поле итоговая стоимость считалась автоматически(цены на комплектующие и автомобили хранятся в регистрах сведений ЦеныНаАвто,ЦеныНаКомлпектующие)
https://imgur.com/a/hIYd5nd

Какой у вас уровень в разработке на 1С? Задание из реальной проф. деятельности или тестовое?

Даже не знаю, учусь только

Можно сделать кнопку "Рассчитать", после нажатия которой, будет сделан запрос к базе данных,к регистрам сведений, который вернет ЦеныНаАвто, ЦеныНаКомлпектующие либо сразу сумму, которую нужно внести в поле итоговая стоимость.

Нет, мне не нужно по кнопке скриншот прикрепил получается при выборе модели что бы  у меня подставлялась сумма из регистра ЦеныНаАвто и сумма тех  комплектующих  которые я выбрал в тч

@Иван, вешайте обработчик на событие выбора элемента и там получайте данные из регистра и заполняйте как нужно.

@Sagittarius а сможете подробно написать этот обработчик, я только только учусь не совсем все понимаю буду очень благодарен если поможете

@Иван, нажимаете на элемент формы ПКМ, в выпадающем меню в разделе "События" выбираете "ПриИзменении". Создастся процедура-обработчик. В ней пишите код по получению и заполнению данных.

@Sagittarius можете написать код?

@Иван, почитайте как работать с запросами
